# change date format in array elements

Tags: ruby, arrays, date

I have certain array elements (strings) that should be formatted as dates (mm/dd/yyyy), and they are currently causing issues when the day portion of the date is a single digit.  I'm assuming the same issue will be happening with the month portion, although I've only seen it with the day portion.  How would I take the elements of the `cells` array, and format them as dates with the format mm/dd/yyyy, with leading zeros if the month or day is a single digit.

The array will always be different, but elements 5, 6 and 7, will always need to be dates.

my array:

```
[1] [
    [0] "297",
    [1] "name",
    [2] "463",
    [3] "value",
    [4] "value1",
    [5] "12/8/2013",
    [6] "12/9/2013",
    [7] "12/9/2013"
],
```

Comment: I dont understand wheither the 0-4 elements shell be changed to date format?

Comment: What have you tried? We can throw code at you but you might have to shoehorn it into place. Show us what you've tried and we can fix what you wrote, plus your question will actually be written correctly then.

Comment: @majioa - no, only 5-7 will be date formatted.  The rest are fine.

Comment: @the Tin Man - I've tried Date.parse(cells[5], "%F")...along with some other variations of that.  .strptime().

Comment: Also, what does "causing issues when the day portion of the date is a single digit" mean? What issues? Date can get confused with formats like you're showing, but you don't give us a clue what you're really seeing.

Answer (score 3):

To change something of the format you say to `mm/dd/yyyy`, try this:

```
sprintf("%02i/%02i/%4i", *(datestr.split("/").map {|i| i.to_i}))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the strings converted to date objects:

```
require 'date'

cells = []
cells[5] = "12/8/2013"
cells[6] = "12/9/2013"
cells[7] = "12/9/2013"

(5..7).each do |i|
  cells[i] = Date.strptime(cells[i], '%m/%d/%Y')
  puts "#{cells[i]} (#{cells[i].class} object)"
end
```

Result:

```
2013-08-12 (Date object)
2013-09-12 (Date object)
2013-09-12 (Date object)
```

Comment: A result of mm/dd/yyyy was requested, not yyyy-dd-mm.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that, and if he only wants the string reformatted, he can look to Linuxios' answer, which returns a string. I started by saying 'If you want the strings converted to date objects'. The date object could then be used in whatever way he wants. The way it's formatted in the result above just happens to be the default string representation of the date object in a simple puts statement, which I only put there to show that the strings have in fact been converted to date objects.

Comment: My apologies, Kai.  I missed your first sentence.

Comment: No worries! I was just about to mention that O-I used strftime, not me, but I see you just corrected that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the array `cells` always has dates at index 5 through 7, the following will update the `cells` array to have the dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format:

```
require 'date'

cells[5..7] = cells[5..7].map { |date| Date.parse(date).strftime('%m/%d/%Y') }
```

Comment: It's good practice to include any required requires in your answers, here require 'date'

Comment: @CarySwoveland Updated. Thanks for the tip. I do a lot of my testing in `pry` and apparently it already has the `Date` class loaded by default. I'll try to do a better job of testing in alternate environments so as not to omit any `require`s that may be necessary for a general solution that will run anywhere.

Comment: I wonder why you can't just use 'cells[5..7].map!' here instead of the repetition in 'cells[5..7] = cells[5..7].map'. I tried it earlier with my own answer, but discovered that it doesn't work. Do you know why #map! doesn't work in this context?

Comment: Don't worry, I answered my own question. #map! only works for Array, not Enumerable.

Comment: Wait, no that's not it. I'm getting myself confused. 'cells[5..7]' returns a new array it seems, so I guess it makes sense that map! isn't touching the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'date'

arr = ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", \
       "12/8/2013", "12/9/2013", "12/9/2013"]

FMT = '%m/%d/%Y'

arr.map! do |e|
  begin
    Date.strptime(e, FMT).strftime(FMT)
  rescue
    e
  end
end

arr # => ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", \
    #     "12/08/2013", "12/09/2013", "12/09/2013"]
```

I just allowed an exception to be raised by `strptime` when `e` does not represent a date with format `FMT`, in which case the corresponding element of `arr` is left unchanged.  Alternatively, something like `if e =~ /^\d*\/\d*\/(\d*)$/...` could be used.

One could instead use `Date.parse(e).strftime(FMT)` (as @O-I did), because the m/d/y order is not changing, but I prefer `strptime` in this situation because it is more demanding of the required date format.

Answer (score 0):

There could be parsing problems you're seeing that changing the format of the string won't fix at all. Consider this:

```
require 'date'

date = Date.parse("12/8/2013") # => #<Date: 2013-08-12 ((2456517j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.day # => 12
```

When Date tries to parse a date in this format, it assumes something that is unintuitive to Americans, but makes sense to the rest of the world. In the U.S., we assume a date is in `mm/dd/yyyy` format. The "right-thinking" people around the rest of the world understand it means `dd/mm/yyyy`. Ruby, being oriented toward the rest of the world uses `dd/mm/yyyy`.

To fix that we have to be a bit smarter about how we parse a date, and actually tell Date what to use:

```
date = Date.strptime("12/8/2013", '%d/%m/%Y') # => #<Date: 2013-08-12 ((2456517j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.day # => 12
```

Or:

```
date = Date.strptime("12/8/2013", '%m/%d/%Y') # => #<Date: 2013-12-08 ((2456635j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
date.day # => 8
```

If all you want to do is add zero-filled fields, you can do that several ways:

```
array = [
  "297",
  "name",
  "463",
  "value",
  "value1",
  "12/8/2013",
  "12/9/2013",
  "12/9/2013"
].map { |e|

  if e[%r=(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)=]
    '%02d/%02d/%04d' % [$1, $2, $3]
  else
    e
  end

}
array # => ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", "12/08/2013", "12/09/2013", "12/09/2013"]
```

Or using a ternary statement for more obscurity:

```
array = [
  "297",
  "name",
  "463",
  "value",
  "value1",
  "12/8/2013",
  "12/9/2013",
  "12/9/2013"
].map { |e|

  e[%r=(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)=] ? '%02d/%02d/%04d' % [$1, $2, $3] : e

}
array # => ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", "12/08/2013", "12/09/2013", "12/09/2013"]
```

If you want to reverse the fields:

```
array = [
  "297",
  "name",
  "463",
  "value",
  "value1",
  "12/8/2013",
  "12/9/2013",
  "12/9/2013"
].map { |e|

  if e[%r=(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)=]
    '%02d/%02d/%04d' % [$2, $1, $3]
  else
    e
  end

}
array # => ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", "08/12/2013", "09/12/2013", "09/12/2013"]
```

Or use the ternary line with the search results swapped.

Or use `scan`:

```
array = [
  "297",
  "name",
  "463",
  "value",
  "value1",
  "12/8/2013",
  "12/9/2013",
  "12/9/2013"
].map { |e|

  numerics = e.scan(/\d+/)
  case numerics.size
  when 3
    '%02d/%02d/%04d' % numerics
  else
    e
  end

}
array # => ["297", "name", "463", "value", "value1", "12/08/2013", "12/09/2013", "12/09/2013"]
```

And if you want to reverse the fields:

```
'%02d/%02d/%04d' % [numerics[1], numerics[0], numerics[2]]
```

Which to use depends on whatever you mean by "causing issues".